# Is it possible to print out the model formual in R

Tags: r

Is it possible to print out the mathematical formula of the model in R. For example,

```
library(usl)

data(raytracer)
usl.model <- usl(throughput ~ processors, data = raytracer)
```

I would like to be able to look at this model's (usl.model) formula. Any ideas wheter is this doable or not?

Answer (score 1):

It is in the `call` slot of the model. You can access it with:

```
> usl.model@call
usl(formula = throughput ~ processors, data = raytracer)
```

A more compact option, eg for display purpose, is:

```
> print(as.formula(usl.model@call), showEnv=FALSE)
throughput ~ processors
```

More generally, on complex objects/lists/etc., `str()` is a nice entry point on the structure.

```
> str(usl.model)
Formal class 'USL' [package "usl"] with 15 slots
..@ frame        :'data.frame': 11 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ throughput: num [1:11] 20 78 130 170 190 200 210 230 260 280 ...
.. ..$ processors: num [1:11] 1 4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 48 ...
.. ..- attr(*, "terms")=Classes 'terms', 'formula' length 3 throughput ~ processors
[.../...]
..@ call         : language usl(formula = throughput ~ processors, data = raytracer)
..@ regr         : chr "processors"
..@ resp         : chr "throughput"
```

You can also add `@` (or `$`) to the object name (eg `usl.model@`) and then press `<tab>`.

Comment: Haven't read the _mathematical_  before formula... my answer was about R's formula.

Answer (score 1):

The 'usl' documentation says:

```
The Universal Scalability Law can be expressed with following
formula. ‘C(N)’ predicts the relative capacity of the system for a
given load ‘N’:

   C(N) = N / (1 + sigma * (N - 1) + kappa * N * (N - 1))
```

I'm not sure how to interpret your question, but would it work to take
the `sigma` and `kappa` coefficients from `summary(usl.model)` and
plug them into this equation?

Update: For the `raytracer` example, it looks like `N` represents the
number of processors and `C(N)` the throughput:

```
N=raytracer$processors;
attach(as.list(usl.model@coefficients))
F=usl.model@scale.factor
data.frame(raytracer, pred=F* N / (1 + sigma * (N - 1) + kappa * N * (N - 1)))
```

This produces:

```
   processors throughput       pred
1           1         20  20.00000
2           4         78  69.55746
3           8        130 118.48067
4          12        170 154.75037
5          16        190 182.70168
6          20        200 204.89242
7          24        210 222.92923
8          28        230 237.87214
9          32        260 250.44877
10         48        280 285.56580
11         64        310 306.91823
```

I'm not sure how sigma and kappa are calculated. The documentation
says that the `default` method uses "a transformation into a 2nd
degree polynom" (citing Gunther) but if the model frame lacks a
predictor with value 1 then it seems to fall back to optimizing the
coefficients (scale factor, sigma and kappa) to minimize the sum of
squared differences between the actual and predicted response variable
(the last two columns above).

Comment: is this model say given the load at any time, what would be the optimal capacity? how do they calculate sigma and kappa?